# How can i limit function-(slot play) just for 5 turn - with do/while loop

Tags: javascript

I wanna create a slot machine with 3 number by javascript - but I want to finish my function when three numbers are equal.
I think that if I write it with do/while it will be work, but I can't do it
this is my js code:

```
 function myF() {
  var slotOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  var slotTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  var slotThree = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

  document.getElementById("slotOne").innerHTML = slotOne;
  document.getElementById("slotTwo").innerHTML = slotTwo;
  document.getElementById("slotThree").innerHTML = slotThree;

  if(slotOne == slotTwo &&  slotTwo == slotThree) {
    document.getElementById("slotOne").style.backgroundColor = "#48bd48";
    document.getElementById("slotTwo").style.backgroundColor = "#48bd48";
    document.getElementById("slotThree").style.backgroundColor = "#48bd48";
    document.getElementById("winner").classList.add("show");
  }
 }
```

this function is set `onclick` attr of a button tag

Comment: by using `counter` variable? Which initially set to 0 and increment after each click!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to comment, if you want to run function for no of times then just use a counter variable to check no of attempts:

Added a reset button to reset the game.

```js
var counter = 0;

function myF() {

 if (counter != 5) {
  counter++;
  document.getElementById("slotLeft").innerHTML = "Try count: " + counter;
  var slotOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  var slotTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  var slotThree = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

  document.getElementById("slotOne").innerHTML = slotOne;
  document.getElementById("slotTwo").innerHTML = slotTwo;
  document.getElementById("slotThree").innerHTML = slotThree;

  if (slotOne == slotTwo && slotTwo == slotThree) {
   document.getElementById("slotOne").style.backgroundColor = "#48bd48";
   document.getElementById("slotTwo").style.backgroundColor = "#48bd48";
   document.getElementById("slotThree").style.backgroundColor = "#48bd48";
   document.getElementById("winner").classList.add("show");
   counter = 5; // Edited this line
  }
 } else {
  console.log('Game over');
 }
}

function myF1(){
  counter = 0;
  document.getElementById("slotOne").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("slotTwo").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("slotThree").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myF()">Check</button>
<button onclick="myF1()">Restart Game</button>


<div id="slotLeft">
</div>
<div id="slotOne">
</div>

<div id="slotTwo">
</div>

<div id="slotThree">
</div>

<div id="winner">
</div>
```

Comment: thanx bro, but when 3 numbers are equal before 5 turns when you click on "check" it turns again

Comment: Check updated answer! you jst need to assign `counter=5` inside if condition!

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function myF() {
  var slotOneElem = document.getElementById("slotOne");
  var slotTwoElem = document.getElementById("slotTwo");
  var slotThreeElem = document.getElementById("slotThree");

  var generateRand = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  }

  return (function () {
    var slotOne   = generateRand();
    var slotTwo   = generateRand();
    var slotThree = generateRand();
    
    slotOneElem.innerHTML = slotOne;
    slotTwoElem.innerHTML = slotTwo;
    slotThreeElem.innerHTML = slotThree;
    
    if (slotOne === slotTwo && slotTwo === slotThree) {
      slotOneElem.style.backgroundColor = "#48bd48";
      slotTwoElem.style.backgroundColor = "#48bd48";
      slotThreeElem.style.backgroundColor = "#48bd48";
      document.getElementById("winner").classList.add("show");
      // Here is the win
      return true;
    } 
    
    return false;
  })();
 }
 
 var finished = myF();
 while (!finished) {
  finished = myF();
 }
```